# JVM Cucumber Execution

Tags: java, cucumber

I am building a framework that is able to execute Selenium instructions and Cucumber instructions. I have created the runner for Cucumber in a seperate empty class with the following code

```
import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
public class RunCukesTest {
}
```

I also will have a processor for Selenium instructions in a separate class.

```
prop.load(ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream("src/main/resources/runConfig.properties"));
            if(prop.getProperty("instructionsheet").contains("InstructionSheets")){
                KeywordProcessor kp = new KeywordProcessor();
            }else if(prop.getProperty("instructionsheet").contains("FeatureFiles")){
                RunCukesTest runCukes = new RunCukesTest();
            }
```

How can I execute the Cucumber runner class if it's an empty class?, do I just create an instance of the runner class for cucumber? or do I have to spacify something else

Answer (score 0):

`@RunWith(Cucumber.class)` is used to integrate cucumber with the existing infrastructure for running JUnit tests. If you start to roll out your own framework, it is worth to look other places. [cucumber.api.cli.Main](https://github.com/mgurov/cucumber-jvm/blob/master/core/src/main/java/cucumber/api/cli/Main.java) could be a good place to start your journey.

Answer (score 0):

The class `RunCukesTest` is a class that will be executed by the JUnit runner `Cucumber.class` since it is annotated with `@RunWith(Cucumber.class)`.

In other words, it will be executed when you run the tests the same way as any other `JUnit` class.

The class is empty, and has to be empty, to force a separation of the execution of Cucumber and the steps supporting the execution.

If you want to execute Cucumber from another context, say your own framework, look at the command line interface. You are able to run its `main()` from any Java class, just call the static method and wait for the result.